# Is there a way to ZIP files using 7z format in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, 7zip

I'm in the process of migrating an SSIS package to Azure Data Factory Pipeline, one of the things it does is ZIPs a large file (around 4gigs) to .7z format. I need to be able to duplicate this function within Azure Data Factory.

I noticed, in the DelimitedText DataSet, that it's not an available option on the 'Compression type' dropdown. Is there a way to use this format? Has anyone else been able to do this?

If 7zip is not an option, does anyone have any suggestions that would be comparable? I checked out .zip and the file is still to big.

I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find an answer for this. Everything revolved around unzipping. I need to ZIP a file to this format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ZipDeflate(.zip)` for the `.7z` format file like below.

These are my source files in a container.

[image]

Create **binary datasets for both source and target**. In the source dataset give the path till the required folder. Here I have given the path till the container `inputdata`.

In the target, give your path and compression type like below.

[image]

Execute the copy activity and you will see the required file in the target with less size.

[image]

**Zipped files:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I really appreciate the explanation! :)

Comment: @NaveenSharma - I accepted the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @Yoseto, Great, it worked for you.